What is the computational scaling of DFT energy vs gradient vs Hessian?
I am trying to understand the computational expense of calculating only the energy, versus the gradient/Hessian of the DFT energy with respect to nuclear coordinates. How do these scale with the size of the system $N$ in the $O(N^p) $ notation?
I have tried to find this in Frank Jensen's Intro to Computational Chemistry, and in papers, but I could not find any reference where these are provided. (I am currently working on a project where I have to compare the timings of these three things on the same systems - and I need to know what is the theoretical scaling).

I gave +1 but the cost of calculating DFT energies is easy to find on Google, it's not clear what you mean by N (for example whether it's the number of electrons, number of atoms, number of basis functions, or a combination of two of these), and it's not clear whether you want automatic, analytic, or numerical derivatives, and most importantly, we ask that everyone ask one question per post, so ideally the question would be focused on gradients or Hessians but not both.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime I didn't explicitly write analytic because that's what most QM packages default to - so I thought it would be obvious. I edited the questions to clarify what my actual question was. I don't see the point of rolling back. I come to the forum to get answers to my questions and if there is a miscommunication somewhere I try to clarify the question.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Now you are not letting me edit the question, because you wrote an answer that does not actually answer my question. I am honestly shocked to see this kind of heavy-handed behaviour. It is certainly not encouraging me to engage in this community more.

I'm treating this case in exactly the same way as every other case in which someone edits a question after it has been answered. It might be hard to see the value of such a policy when your own question and desires go against it, but it's a policy widely supported (and you'll see not just me, but others also rolling back questions when they see edits made after an answer was written).  I'm not removing the part in my answer about numerical derivatives, and neither should the question be changed to make that part irrelevant. The part about basis sets and atoms completely changes the question.

Energies
An excellent answer to this question was provided here, and arose immediately with this Google search.
Numerical gradients
Derivatives of energies with respect to a nuclear coordinate can be calculated numerically by calculating two energies, then calculating the difference between them and dividing the result by the difference in the nuclear coordinate values. This means that the cost of doing a derivative calculation, is only two times the cost of doing an energy calculation, and therefore does not change the power $p$ in the $O(N^p)$ notation, in which $N$ is basically the number of electrons (see the first link that I provided for more details about what $N$ is). This procedure will be repeated many times if you have a lot of nuclear coordinates and want the gradient, and if you want to try different "finite difference" sizes and seek convergence with respect to that parameter, but this does not affect the $O(N^p)$ cost based on the way that you asked the question, with basically the number of electrons being the "size of the system". If you want the $O(N^p M^q)$  cost, in which $N$ is basically the number of electrons and $M$ is the number of nuclear coordinates, then it's a different question, which we can also answer if you post that question next.
Numerical Hessians
If you use one of the formulas for "second order" derivatives found here, then the cost becomes "three times" the original cost, rather than "two times" the original cost, so everything that I said about the power not changing for gradients, is also true for Hessians.
Analytic and automatic derivatives
If you want analytic derivatives, it might cost a bit more than just "two times" or "three times" the original cost, but the advantages over the above-described numerical derivatives, would be that you don't have to do the above procedure for each nuclear coordinate change, and you don't have to repeat the calculation for different "finite difference" step sizes in order to get numerical convergence. The power is unlikely to change though, and certainly the power wouldn't change if you were to use automatic derivatives.
Conclusion
If you plot the cost of the energy, gradient, and Hessian calculations with respect to the cube of the number of electrons, you will theoretically get three straight lines with different slopes, which indicates that  the $O(N^p)$ cost is the same for these three types of calculations, but the pre-factors that are hidden under the $O()$ are different. Practically (not theoretically), you would have to take into account the details that were explained in the first link that I provided.

For analytic gradients, I agree, but for analytic Hessians the scaling (without using low order scaling tricks) is $O(N^pM)$, because one has to solve a CPHF equation with $O(M)$ right hand side (RHS) vectors. Solving the CPHF equation for a constant number of RHS vectors scales the same as SCF itself, but it also scales linearly with the number of RHS vectors. With complicated tricks it is possible to get rid of the $M$ factor (see https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4908131), but this usually requires $p$ to be first reduced to 1 or 2 from the original value of 3, which is already complicated.

@wzkchem5 what is M? In my answer it was the number of nuclear coordinates, in which case the scaling with respect to N is still the same whether you are calculating energies, gradients or Hessians.

In my answer the definition of $M$ is the same as in your post. Now I understand you may mean the power of $N$, not the total power of $M$ and $N$. I was in the mindset of the quantum chemistry community, where (when the basis set size per atom is held fixed) it is assumed that $M$ scales linearly with $N$ and one tends to talk about their total power.

@wzkchem5 I don't think it's fair to say that the whole quantum chemistry community assumes that M scales linearly with N, because so much work is on dinuclear, trinuclear, and other small polynuclear molecules. I think the biggest molecule in the GW100 dataset has 16 nuclei, and the enormous GMTKN30 dataset which is composed of many smaller and widely used datasets, also doesn't have very big molecules. Even if M=500, if we assume that they are all carbon, then we have N=3000 electrons (linear scaling but with a prefactor of 6). I'm curious to see any reference that combines M and N!

I have to agree with wzchem5, I want to know the total power including the pre-factor of N (considering the same basis set but different number of atoms). Maybe the question was not clear - I will edit it.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime That's why I said "when the basis set size per atom is held fixed". Obviously the whole quantum chemistry community does not assume $M$ scales linearly with $N$, but if the basis set size per atom is held fixed, then $M$ has to scale linearly with $N$! But you are right that I shouldn't have said "assume" - it's a necessary conclusion, not an assumption.

Once someone has answered a question, changes to the question will almost always be rolled back. Your question didn't say whether you want analytic or numerical or automatic derivatives, so I gave an answer for all three. If you only wanted me to focus on analytic derivatives, it would have been better if that was made clear in the original question. Also, in your last comment you said that you want the pre-factor. But your question said you wanted the answer in big O notation, which by definition hides the pre-factor under the big O.  A new post can ask for the pre-factor.

@wzkchem5 The question did not say that the basis size per atom is held fixed, and more often than not, it is not held fixed. Anyway, if we assume that there's N=10 basis functions per atom and that the cost per basis function is N^3 (this would be somewhat true if N were the number of electrons rather than basis functions), then for M atoms we have a cost of (10M)^3 for energies. If we want numerical derivatives wrt the XYZ coordinates of M atoms, then we can repeat the calculation 3M times and get a cost of 3000M^4 = O(M^4) when really the cost is O(N^3*M) which is very different.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime It's a good point that not everyone intends to hold the basis size per atom fixed. But the cost is only $O(N^3M)$ when $N$ stands for the total number of basis functions. If $N$ stands for the number of basis functions per atom, then the cost would be $O(N^3M^4)$.

@wzkchem5 Most people would use fewer basis functions for H than for "first row" elements such as C, N, O, etc., and would use more basis functions for transition metal elements, and even more for lanthanides and actinides. You are correct that if N is the number of basis functions/atom, the cost would be O(N^3 M^4) if the cost per basis function is O(N^3). In my last comment, I made an error when I wrote "N=10 basis functions per atom", because I always meant that N is the number of total basis functions. All of the subsequent analysis in that comment was based on N being the total.

I mean I wanted to know the scaling specifically to compare timings as I wrote in my question - I mentioned the big O notation because that's how I see these things represented in papers - if they exclude the pre-factor by definition then its not what I want. But do you know any references about the differences in pre-factor between energy, gradient and Hessian?

Also I thought that it would be clear I was asking about analytic gradients because numeric ones are simply repeating the same calculation so it would be trivial to get the scaling. Maybe we are talking past each other - but I don't think what you wrote really answers my question.

You say that it's trivial to get the scaling for numerical derivatives, but it's far more trivial to get the scaling for DFT energies, as the screenshot of the Google search in my answer demonstrates. If one is asking for the answer to provide the scaling for DFT energies and gradients, then I don't think it's unreasonable for the answer to provide the scaling for numerical gradients, especially when we are asked for O(N^p) scaling, since N for DFT energies is usually the number of electrons, independent of the number of atoms, so the O(N^p) cost is the same for analytic/numerical derivatives.

The big-O notation by definition hides the prefactor. O(N^p) = O(k*N^p) for any pre-factor k. Also, if the number of atoms M is constant, then O(N^p) = O(N^p M^q), so O(N^p) = O(N^3) is the answer for energies, gradients, and Hessians (modulo the adjustments discussed in the first link in my answer). Since this question asked for the answer in O(N^p) form, then a question about the pre-factor hidden under the big-O, would be most appropriate in a new post. There you can also specify that you want analytic derivatives instead of numerical ones, and perhaps also you want O(N^p M^q).
